# VS Code, does not accept suggest on tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am currently working on VS Code with GitHub Copilot.

But when I have a suggestion:

[image]

And I press "Tab" to accept the suggestion, Vs Code adds a tab in the code:

[image]

Someone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @mhkarami97 I posted it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

In fact VS Code has a prioritization for the same shortcuts.
A custom shortcut is more prioritized than a default shortcut.
If you have a shortcut for your `tab` key in your VS Code, that can disorganize the prioritization of the default shortcut.

### Solution

I don't find a solution to give a prioritization for a shortcut, so I set the default for all shortcuts using the `tab` key:

[image]

Note: is important to click on *"Reset keybinding"* to take the default prioritization.

### Other solution

It's probably possible that VS Code gives a prioritization with the date of the last update of your shortcut. But I don't try this solution because you need to update all the shortcuts and we have several shortcuts for `tab` key.